# With $23$ programs queued to run on a quad core processor, any of which that can run on multiple cores, how many different assignments are there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this discrete math question that I do not seem to quite understand. Full question:

There are $23$ programs queued to run on a quad-core processor (processor with four cores). If each program can only be assigned to at most one core, and each core will have one program running on it, how many different combinations of programs can be run at the same time?

If any of the programs can be run on multiple cores at the same time, how many different assignments are there now?

My solution:
For the first question, I got $C(23,4)$ since out of $23$ programs, only $4$ programs will run at the same time and the order in which the programs are picked does not matter.

For the second question, however, I am unsure what the wording of this question is trying to point me towards. My thought process is that since each core will still have $1$ program running on it at a given point in time and that any program can be run on multiple cores at the same time, then there is the possibility that the same program can be reused over multiple cores. Therefore, taking into account the number of program options over the four cores, the answer would have to be $(23)(23)(23)(23)$. Is this how the problem should be done?

Comment: Those are the same answers I would give, but I'm not quite sure about the second.  It counts program $1$ running on cores $1$ and $2$ and program $2$ running on cores $3$ and $4$ as different from program $1$ running on cores $3$ and $4$ and program $2$ running on cores $1$ and $2$.  This is what "assignment" means to me, but it's a bit different in spirit from the first part, where we only care what tasks run, not where they run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i = 1, \ldots, 23$, let $x_i$ be the number of cores that program $i$ is running on. Notice that $0 \leq x_i \leq 4$ for all $i$. We want to know how many solutions there are to the equation
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{23} = 4.
$$

This sort of counting problem is sometimes called stars and bars, which is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

In this case, the number of solutions is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, where $n = 4$ and $k = 23$.